# upgrade Spring Boot parent starter from 1.5 into 2.1.1.Release

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

Getting this below exception as i am trying to upgrade by Spring Boot parent starter from 1.5 into 2.1.1.Release, but not getting any compilation or any Exception in my Project. Is that i am missing anything here.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.nbcuni.compass.schedule.ScheduleServiceApplication.main(ScheduleServiceApplication.java:58)
```

Same kind of Issue in another service as well.

```
2018-12-18 12:31:58,999 INFO  [  ] --- [background-preinit] o.h.v.i.u.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.13.Final
2018-12-18 12:31:59,851 ERROR [  ] --- [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.nbcuni.compass.title.TServiceApplication.main(TServiceApplication.java:34)
```

**pom.xml**

Latest upgraded version related to Spring Boot starter parent

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
        <springfox.version>2.6.0</springfox.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version> 
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Registry & Discovery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Config Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>

            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
              <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>

         </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>titles</finalName>
        <plugins>

 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>  


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.8</version>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <!-- implementation is needed only for Maven 2 -->
                                <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <!-- implementation is needed only for Maven 2 -->
                                        <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.00</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.junit.junit-tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-tools</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>D:/.../test9/titles/Junit-Jar/Junit-Jar/junit-tools.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.junit.jmockit</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>D:/.../test9/titles/Junit-Jar/Junit-Jar/jmockit.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>  -->


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>


</project>
```

Comment: Do you have project on github/ any other code hosting service?

Comment: Check the Java version you are using

Comment: Your Jdk must be equal or greater 1.8

Comment: @Jonathan Johx Using jdk 1.8 only

Comment: Please add your POM. Potentially a spring cloud dependency is out of date.

Comment: @Dareen - pom.xml for reference ,please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Spring Cloud `Brixton` which is EOL and quite old, even for Spring Boot. You can't just upgrade Spring Boot and not look at other versions in your build file as those have to be kept in sync.

For the most part, Spring Boot helps you with a curated dependency management for a number of dependencies. Unfortunately, it cannot do that for components that build on top of Spring Boot (and Spring Cloud is one of those).

The [documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) provides the compatible versions. At the time of writing, `Greenwich` is not even GA. You can also bootstrap a project on https://start.spring.io/ with a could dependency to look at a recommended build.

Finally https://start.spring.io/info tells you exactly what we're using ourselves.

Comment: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Greenwich.M1 has not been downloaded from it before.